# Is enum { a } e = 1; valid?

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer

A simple question: is `enum { a } e = 1;` valid?

In other words: does assigning a value, which *isn't present* in the set of values of enumeration constants, lead to well-defined behavior?

Demo:

```
$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ icc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
t0.c(1): warning #188: enumerated type mixed with another type
# note: the same warning for enum { a } e = 0;

$ cl t0.c /std:c11 /Za /c
<nothing>
```

Comment: [C11 6.5.16.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1) states: "arithmetic type = arithmetic type" is OK... `enum`s are arithmetic types, integer constant are arithmetic types so you're good **as long as you don't cause overflow**.

Comment: [6.7.2.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p4) - *Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type.*

Comment: You might like `clang -Weverything ...`

Comment: Even if authorised this can lead to hard code maintenance.

Comment: This sort of coding will bite hard in `switch` statements that have a `case` for each enumerated value but no `default`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just to be sure: per definition of "compatible" does it follow that "char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type" is compatible with enumerated type?

Comment: @pmg Where it says that enumerated type is arithmetic type? I see that "Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types".

Comment: @pmor: [C11 6.2.5p17](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p17): "The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called integer types." and next point (6.2.5p18): "Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the C18 standard in 6.7.2.2:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

So yes `enum { a } e = 1;` is valid. `e` is a 'integer' type so it can take the value `1`. The fact that `1` is not present as an enumeration value is no issue.
The enumeration members only give handy identifiers for some of possible values.

Comment: "*The enumeration members only give handy identifiers for some of possible values*" -- per the language semantics, yes, but this is not usually the programmer's intended usage model.  Programmers using `enums` need to bear in mind this disconnection between their mental model and the actual language semantics.

Comment: Even if it is 'allowed', it is bad style and to be avoided.

Comment: it's pretty common in flags though. you don't name every combinations.

Comment: Despite the many upvotes, I have a doubt that this clause makes the statelent valid.  Indeed,  "*shall be compatible with*" means that there could be a conversion from the one to the other,  but it does not guarantee that all char or int values will be legal in such a conversion.  Moreover "*shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration*"  just guarantees that the type chosen shall be capable of holding any of the defined member values (in OP's example it's just 0).  It doesn't guarantee the contrary.

Answer (score 6):

#### Valid in C

This is valid in C as per e.g. the [202x working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2346.pdf):

> **6.7.2.2/4** Each enumerated type **shall be compatible with** char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is **implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration**

particularly due to the "compatible type" requirement:

> **6.2.7/1** Two types have compatible type **if their types are the same**. Additional rules [...]

---

#### ...  implementation-defined and possible unspecified/undefined behavior in C++14 and earlier/C++17 and later

Whilst out of scope for this Q&A (C tag, not C++), it may be interesting to point out that the same does not hold for C++, where "C style" unscoped enums with no fixed underlying type have subtle differences from C. For details about the C++ case, see the following Q&A:

- [Is enum E { a } e = E(2); valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032456/is-enum-e-a-e-e2-valid)

Comment: The question was always tagged C, so the discussion of C++ behavior is not particularly relevant here. I'd suggest posting a new self-answered question that's basically the same as this one, but for C++. (You can link to this Q and ask "this is what it does in C, what about C++?")

Comment: @cigien Fair point, I'll look into that later this weekend.

Comment: @cigien [Broke out C++ part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032456/is-enum-e-a-e-e2-valid/71032457#71032457), thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

I can find no reference in [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (in terms of "constraints") that prohibits an assignment to a `enum` type such as yours (and the C18 Standard quoted in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988952/10871073) uses essentially identical wording).

However, that C11 Draft does provide this, in **Annexe I – Common Warnings**:

> 1     An implementation may generate warnings in many
> situations, none of which are specified as part of this International
> Standard. The following are a few of the more common situations.
> 2
> …
>    —    A value is given to an object of an
> enumerated type other than by assignment of an enumeration constant
> that is a member of that type, or an enumeration object that has the
> same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumerated
> type (6.7.2.2).

But that suggested warning could equally well apply to an assignment like `enum { a } e = 0;`, where the **value** of the RHS *corresponds to* a valid enumeration constant but it is *actually* neither an enumeration constant of the type nor an object of that enumerated type.

Comment: I think your reason why `enum { a } e = 0;` may generate a warning is wrong. The reason should be because `0` is not an enumeration constant (even though it has the same type and value as the enumeration constant `a` that is a member of the enumerated type).

Comment: @IanAbbott Fair comment. I'll edit, but need to think a bit ... because the RHS can be *either* an enumeration constant *or* another object of the same enumerated **type**.

Comment: In this case, there is precisely one object of the enumerated type, namely the variable `e`. Since the enumerated type has no tag, it is impossible to create further objects of the same type after the current declaration because there is no way to refer to the type (except by using extensions to the C language such as `typeof(e) another_e;` in GCC).

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, in this particular case. However, the warning in the Annexe is more general. (Also, I *think* that a "compatible enum type" could be created?)

Comment: A "compatible enum type" can only be created in a separate translation unit.

Comment: @IanAbbott Re: "0 is not an enumeration constant": In this case should an implementation distinguish between `case 0:` and `case a:`?

Comment: @pmor In this case, `a` and `0` have the same value, so both `case` labels cannot appear in the same `switch` statement. As for whether `case 0:` might generate a warning when the switch control expression has an enumerated type (and is not a constant expression), well Annexe I has nothing to say about that!

Comment: Further to previous discussion of compatible enumerated types, each enumerated type will be compatible with *some* integer type, and I guess that if two enumerated types are compatible with the *same* integer type, then they must be compatible with each other, assuming compatibility is a transitive property.

Comment: @IanAbbott: The C and C++ Standards often fail to consider when they should say "All defined uses of construct X are equivalent to Y" versus "X is equivalent to Y in all cases where either is defined".  Further, even in cases where the Standard doesn't say constructs are transitively equivalent, compilers will sometimes combine upstream optimizations that would only be valid if they were treated as transitively equivalent, with downstream optimizations which don't support constructs relied upon by the upstream ones.

Answer (score 2):

### In short

The validity of `enum { a } e = 1;` is ensured for the particular value of `1`, a combination of different reasons, based on the definition of enum types, conversion rules of compatible types,  and compatibility guarantees.

*Spoiler alert: it's much more complex in C18 than the quote of any single paragraph (see my comment under the accepted answer).*

### Full explanation

I'll quote the C18 standard step by step (N2176 to be precise).  Highlights are from me.

First, we know that `enum { a }` is an integer type:

> **6.2.5. Types**
> 16: An **enumeration** comprises a set of named integer constant values. Each distinct enumeration constitutes a **different enumerated type**.
> 17: The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the **enumerated types** are collectively called **integer types**.

Then,  we can demonstrate that if `enum { a }` is an integer type "large enough" to hold `1`, the assignment would valid (because there is no explicit statement of the contrary):

> **6.2.7 Compatible types and composite types**
> 1:Two types have **compatible type** if their types are the same. (...)
>
> **6.3. Conversions**
> 2: Unless explicitly stated otherwise, **conversion** of an operand value **to a compatible type** causes **no change to the value or the representation**.
>
> **6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
> 4: Each enumerated **type shall be compatible with** char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

But is the type large enough? From here we deduct that the value of `a` is `0`.  Since it's also the largest enum constant in the set, we can deduct that `enum { a }` is "at least" compatible with `char`:

> **6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
> 3: (...) An enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.

In conclusion, the assignment is legal, because the litteral `1` is also compatible with `char`.

### Beware of implementation dependent assumptions!

But be careful, such an integer assignment is not necessarily valid for whatever integer you choose:

```
enum { a } = INT_MAX;  // Implementation dependent, see J.3.9 
enum { a, b=INT_MAX } = 1024;  // ok: b requires int as compatible type
```

In the first case, the enum is only guaranteed to be compatible with `char`.  But we have no guarantee that it's compatible with an `int`:

> **J.3. Implementation-defined behavior**
> (...)
> **J.3.9. Structures, unions, enumerations, and bit-fields
> (...)
>
> - The integer type compatible with each enumerated type (6.7.2.2).

In the second case,  we used specification of an inteer value to force a compatible type with `int`.