# Is it possible to know the range of an non-fixed enumerator?

Tags: c++, enums, c++14

Is there a way to know the range of values of an enumeration? I was expecting some `type_traits` template like `std::numeric_limits`, but I have found no one.

For example:

```
enum enm { A = -5, B = 3 };

std::cout << std::range_of_enum<enm>::min() << ', '
          << std::range_of_enum<enm>::max() << std::endl;
// Prints -8, 7 with two's complement representation, and -7, 7 
// with one's complement representation.
```

**NOTE:** For those who don't know what is the "enumeration range" (a non-standard term though), go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632176/motivation-of-the-enumeration-range-definition-with-non-fixed-type).

Comment: Unfortunately no. There's a complex set of rules that determines the valid range, but no ready-made way to access the result. (Also, the rules are [allegedly wrong](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/1349).)

Comment: What do you mean by "range"?

Comment: @NeilButterworth http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum and search for `static_cast`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: See [dcl.enum]p8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The C++2a/2b reflection proposal(s) I have looked at appear way more than strong enough to calculate this, if they lack a direct trait.  I do not know the likelyhood of them being standardized in 2020, nor the text of the most current proposal to guarantee 100%.